# Custom layout Next.js 13 AppRouter, hydration error

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to wrap the _app.js file with a custom layout as I did earlier like the following, so I can have a Navbar at top and everything else in a container:

```
//layout.js file
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

export default function Layout(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <br />
            <Container>
                {props.children}
            </Container>
            <br />
        </>
    )
}
```

```
// _app.js file
import '@/styles/bootstrap.min.css';
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "@/components/Layout";
import { SWRConfig } from "swr";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <SWRConfig
          value={{
            fetcher: async (url) => {
              const res = await fetch(url);

              // If the status code is not in the range 200-299,
              // we still try to parse and throw it.
              if (!res.ok) {
                const error = new Error(
                  "An error occurred while fetching the data."
                );
                // Attach extra info to the error object.
                error.info = await res.json();
                error.status = res.status;
                throw error;
              }
              return res.json();
            },
          }}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </SWRConfig>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}
```

But in Next.js 13 the layout.js file in app folder looks like:

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
   
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}><Navbar /><br />{children}</body>
    </html>
    
  )
}
```

and if I try to wrap the HTML part with the layout component

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return ( 
<Layout> <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}><Navbar /><br />{children}</body>
    </html>
</Layout>
)
}
```

It gives me a hydration error. Could you also explain the hydration error in simple terms with examples. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the error? And I'm assuming you're using the PageRouter, correct?

Comment: Actually i just noticed you said app folder, does that mean you're using the AppRouter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First of all

You should not wrap your `html` inside anything because it's the root of everything in nextjs13 newly introduced app router structure.

### Migrating from `pages` directory and `_app` file to `app` directory and `page` files

In versions before 13 You had a folder named `pages` that would manage your pages and routing, and you had a `_app` file that would wrap all your pages.
But in version 13 you have an `app` folder containing some `page.js` files inside some folders in a structured way and one or more `layout` files. `app` folder manages routing and `layout` file is something like the old `_app` file that wraps all your pages.
So there is no meaning in using your old `<Layout>` component inside `RootLayout` component. Because they're the same thing only with different logic. Please take a look at [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing) to see how they all work together.
Try wrapping only `children` with bootstrap wrapper, just like what you did in your old `layout.js` file:

```
//RootLayout component 
<html lang="en">
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <Navbar />
    <br />
    <Container>{/*bootstrap container*/}
      {children}
    </Container>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Next Steps:

When using third party providers in your layout you need to make sure they updated their code and strictly marked it as a client component by including `"use client"` in top of their exported code.
If not, you will get an error about using hooks in a server component.
And according to [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required)

> The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component.

So the only way is to create a wrapper client component and wrap your third party library inside of it:

```
//BootstrapProvider.tsx
"use client";

import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
export default function BootstrapProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <Container>
      {children}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

And use it in your layout like this:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        <br />
        <BootstrapProvider>
          {children}
        </BootstrapProvider>
        <br />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Read [migration docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#migrating-from-pages-to-app) for your future problems.